# I can git clone cmd but it dosen't work in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, aws-codecommit

I can git clone cmd but it dosen't work in eclipse

How to fix it?

Credential is correct

[image]

The image's content is like that:

> An error occured when trying to contact https://git-codecommit-~~
>
> Possible reasons:
>
> - Incorrect URL
> - No network connection (e.g wrong proxy settings)
> - .git is missing at end of repository URL
> - SSL host could not be verified (set http.sslverify=false in Git configuration)

Comment: Please, fix the image description.

Comment: Please show the working command line and the _Clone Git Repository_ dialog. Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: Try to use the SSH path instead http

Comment: Have you double checked all of those possible reasons?